# errors in a generic stack class (most seem to do with underflow inputs)

Tags: java, arrays, stack, underflow

Here's the code

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class MyGenericStack<Item> implements MyGenericStackInterface<Item> {
private java.util.ArrayList<Item> list = new java.util.ArrayList<Item>();

/*
 * Retrieve the item that was most recently added to the stack,
 * which is the item at the top of the stack.
 * The item is removed from the stack.
 */
public Item pop( ) throws EmptyStackException{
    if (isEmpty()) throw new EmptyStackException();
    else{
        Item thing = null;
        if(list.get(size()-1) == null){
            thing = null;
        }
        else{

            thing = list.get(size()-1);
        }
        return thing;
    }
}

/*
 * Retrieve the item at the top of the stack.
 * Does not modify the stack.
 */
public Item peek( ) throws EmptyStackException{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    else{return list.get(size()-1);

    }

};

/*
 * Add item to the top of the stack.
 */
public void push( Item item ){

    list.add(item);
};

/*
 * Return true if the stack is empty
 */
public boolean isEmpty( ){
    return list.isEmpty();

}

/*
 * Return the number of items on the stack
 */
public int size( ){
    return list.size();
};


}
```

The problem is when I test all of the cases I get these **8 errors**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: IsEmpty Error: isEmpty did not return true for empty stack after underflow.

java.lang.AssertionError: Peek Error: Peeking at null value on top of stack did not return null.

java.lang.AssertionError: Pop Error: Popping null value off stack did not return null.

java.lang.AssertionError: Push Error: Pushed multiple string values, but failed to retrieve them in order (via pop).

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException (this test was labelled testReverseStringWithStack)

java.lang.AssertionError: Size Error: Size did not return correct size after pushes after underflow.

java.lang.AssertionError: Size Error: Size did not return 0 for empty stack after underflow.

java.lang.AssertionError: Push Error: Pushed multiple int values, but failed to retrieve them in order (via pop).
```

is there any way I can fix these? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cloud you show us the code of the tests ? It looks to me more of a problem with the test than with the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `isEmpty()` method is defined in terms of the underlying `List<>` field but your `pop()` method doesn't actually remove an item from the list - it only calls `get()` on the list, which doesn't remove the item from the list. So after a few calls to `push()` / `pop()` you're going to find that `isEmpty()` and `size()` are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The issues I can see is, when `pop()` is called, then item is not removed from the list. remove the item which you return from the list. This should sove the errors related to underflow.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I feel a bit silly. The problem was that I just forgot to add in "list.remove(size-1)" to the pop method. Would have never noticed it if someone hadn't pointed it out, thanks.